# Is there a way to wrap inner text with a div except for the first line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to automate some HTML to use a jQuery accordion script with it. There are a bunch of pages with this HTML on it so if possible, it would be awesome if this could be formatted with just one class. Here's what I'm hoping to do:

**Starting HTML:**

```
<ul class="accordionize">
<li>
   <h3>Heading numero uno</h3>
   <p>Street art fanny pack viral drinking vinegar food truck, jean shorts cray pop-up flexitarian selvage. Asymmetrical cardigan craft beer lo-fi normcore. Plaid gentrify synth four loko.</p>
   <p>Cred keytar gluten-free, artisan 8-bit viral ethnic asymmetrical messenger bag. Ennui occupy next level, direct trade ethical authentic drinking vinegar. Locavore salvia kitsch, try-hard butcher distillery cred ugh fanny pack ethnic.</p>
   <ul>
   <li>
      <h4>Another subheading</h4>
      <p>Pinterest post-ironic before they sold out, Pitchfork Intelligentsia crucifix art party American Apparel mustache YOLO chia umami Brooklyn 8-bit.</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h4>Second subheading</h4>
      <p>Roof party raw denim kale chips banjo trust fund Intelligentsia locavore Blue Bottle. Echo Park selfies Tonx Pinterest, crucifix mumblecore bicycle rights YOLO.</p>
   </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to add a jQuery script to target `.accordionize` and have it turn the HTML into the following:

**Ideal resulting HTML: (the goal)**

```
<ul class="accordionize">
<li>
   <h3 class="accordion-trigger">Heading numero uno</h3>
   <div class="accordion-content">
   <p>Street art fanny pack viral drinking vinegar food truck, jean shorts cray pop-up flexitarian selvage. Asymmetrical cardigan craft beer lo-fi normcore. Plaid gentrify synth four loko.</p>
   <p>Cred keytar gluten-free, artisan 8-bit viral ethnic asymmetrical messenger bag. Ennui occupy next level, direct trade ethical authentic drinking vinegar. Locavore salvia kitsch, try-hard butcher distillery cred ugh fanny pack ethnic.</p>
   <ul>
   <li>
      <h4 class="accordion-trigger">Another subheading</h4>
      <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>Pinterest post-ironic before they sold out, Pitchfork Intelligentsia crucifix art party American Apparel mustache YOLO chia umami Brooklyn 8-bit.</p>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h4 class="accordion-trigger">Second subheading</h4>
      <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>Roof party raw denim kale chips banjo trust fund Intelligentsia locavore Blue Bottle. Echo Park selfies Tonx Pinterest, crucifix mumblecore bicycle rights YOLO.</p>
      </div>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I can get part of it to work with the following script, but the first header needs to be outside the `.accordion-content`. Also, I'd like a cleaner way to target just the first element in the `li`, regardless of if it's an `h3` or an `h4`. Thanks, appreciate any ideas!

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $('.accordionize li').wrapInner('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
   $('.accordionize li h3').first().addClass('accordion-trigger');
   $('.accordionize li h4').first().addClass('accordion-trigger');
});
</script>
```

**Current resulting HTML: (incorrect)**

```
<ul class="accordionize">
<li>
   <div class="accordion-content">
   <h3 class="accordion-trigger">Heading numero uno</h3>
   <p>Street art fanny pack viral drinking vinegar food truck, jean shorts cray pop-up flexitarian selvage. Asymmetrical cardigan craft beer lo-fi normcore. Plaid gentrify synth four loko.</p>
   <p>Cred keytar gluten-free, artisan 8-bit viral ethnic asymmetrical messenger bag. Ennui occupy next level, direct trade ethical authentic drinking vinegar. Locavore salvia kitsch, try-hard butcher distillery cred ugh fanny pack ethnic.</p>
   <ul>
   <li>
      <div class="accordion-content">
      <h4 class="accordion-trigger">Another subheading</h4>
      <p>Pinterest post-ironic before they sold out, Pitchfork Intelligentsia crucifix art party American Apparel mustache YOLO chia umami Brooklyn 8-bit.</p>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="accordion-content">
      <h4 class="accordion-trigger">Second subheading</h4>
      <p>Roof party raw denim kale chips banjo trust fund Intelligentsia locavore Blue Bottle. Echo Park selfies Tonx Pinterest, crucifix mumblecore bicycle rights YOLO.</p>
      </div>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the part "but the first header needs to be outside the .accordion-content" - but for your second question, a cleaner approach to target the first child of the li element, regardless of type, would be: $('.accordionize li > :first').addClass('accordion-trigger');

Comment: Sorry, I mean the resulting HTML needs to have the first header not included in the .accordion-content div. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

This one isn't picky about which element is the first in the li (and it's prettier)

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.accordionize li').wrapInner('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
    $('.accordionize li div').children(":first-child").addClass('accordion-trigger').each(function() {
        $(this).prependTo($(this).parent().parent());
    });
});
</script>
```

**Previous answer:**
Not exactly the cleanest way to achieve it, but this will work:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.accordionize li').wrapInner('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
    $('.accordionize li h3').first().addClass('accordion-trigger');
    $('.accordionize li h4').first().addClass('accordion-trigger');
    $('.accordionize li h3').each(function(){
        $(this).prependTo($(this).parent().parent());
    });

    $('.accordionize li h4').each(function(){
        $(this).prependTo($(this).parent().parent());
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just wrapping the `p` tags with `accordion-trigger`, right?

If the `h3`/`h4` elements will always be first in the list, you could do:

```
$('.accordionize li p').wrap('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
$('.accordionize li').children().first().addClass("accordion-trigger");
```

Comment: There is a child `ul` too to be wrapped.

Comment: This is close! This works if I swap the order of the two lines (otherwise it just ends up as <div class="accordion-content accordion-trigger"), but there's still the matter of keeping the first child outside of the div.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to move the first element out regardless of element type, you can do

```
$('.accordionize li').each(function(){
  var header=$(this).children().first().addClass('accordion-trigger');
  $(this).wrapInner('<div class="accordion-content"></div>')
    .prepend(header);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maMcw/1/

Comment: This is pretty spot on, thanks!! Any ideas on how to combine this with the above script, so that it always targets the first element in the li? I thought just adding .children().first() to the fourth line in your script would do it and switching the target to '.accordionize li', but it's a little off.

Comment: Added a version that's element-agnostic

Comment: Close but the revision adds the first heading to each li, not each first child to it's parent li. @aecend got it with their latest comment, thanks!

Comment: Good point. Fixed now. This one should work for some cases that aecend's doesn't (when there are `<div>`s inside the `<li>`s) but that may just be nitpicking.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a pretty simple solution here. You just need to fix your jQuery selectors.

```
$(function() {
   $('.accordionize li').wrapInner('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
   $('.accordionize h3').first().addClass('accordion-trigger');
   $('.accordionize h4').first().addClass('accordion-trigger');
});
```

Also take a look at [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3b43/). Obviously, it won't show the accordion effect because you did not provide the javascript for it, but if you inspect the DOM you can see that the classes are working. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.accordionize li').wrapInner('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
   $('.accordionize li h3').first().addClass('accordion-trigger')
                                   .before('.accordion-content');
   $('.accordionize li h4').first().addClass('accordion-trigger')
                                   .before('.accordion-content');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the answers work well for the h tags but are missing the mark on wrapping the paragraphs properly. In order to wrap all the paragraphs with the `<div class="accordion-content"></div>` use the following.

```
 $('.accordionize li p').addClass("accordionize-paragraphs").wrapAll('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
```

**update:** this doesn't solve it either after further testing - above answer by CupawnTae works for me.